# How do I get rid of the annoying ctrl+backspace behaviour in MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop (linux version), ctrl+backspace clears all the linebreaks till the last word/char block, and delete that.

For example:

```
qwe asd
.
.
.
_
```

(where _ is my cursor focus is on, and . are line breaks, pressing ctrl+backspace will return me this:

```
qwe _
```

instead of:

```
qwe asd
.
.
_
```

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The work breaking logic is configurable.

In *Preferences->Text Editor->Behavior*, change the work break mode. You probably want the *SharpDevelop* mode.

As ThinkJet said, because MD is a OSS project you can of course write a new word break mode if none of the existing ones fits your needs.